# Does c++ move semantics save resources in every situation?

Tags: c++, move, copy-constructor

I know that C++ move semantics is supposed to save processor power and memory since

```
Move::Move(Shallow&& source) noexcept      // Move constructor
{
    data = source.data;       // Assume data is an array of size = size and all initiated to a user specific value
    size = source.size;
    source.size =0;
    source.data ={nullptr};
}
```

supposing that all array indexes are initialized to a specific variable, so that the move semantic will just save array pointer in memory and nulls out the the source array, like in the example above, This will prevent a new array to be created dynamically if we use a copy constructor (Deep copy constructor to be specific ) But

1) Is there any benefit using move constructor if we assume that **data** is just a simple integer or 
  even a **very large uninitialized array** 
2) This move constructor seems pretty much the same as just calling copy constructor with a **shallow 
   copying like**

```
Copy::Copy(const &source){        // A shallow copy
        data = source.data;       // Assume data is an array of size = size
        size = source.size;
}
```

The only difference of course is Nulling data , and size in move construct , so is there any performance improvement between Both pieces of code above in terms of memory and performance, since Nulling the data pointer and size doesn't actually save us space or memory right, or i miss something here.

This question so that i can know when to use shallow copying or Move semantics and if there is any difference between them (except for nulling down of attributes in the move way).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there any benifet using move constructor if we assume that data is just a simple integer or even a very large uninitialized array

No.

> This move constructor seems pretty much the same as just calling copy constructor with a shallow copying.

It is.

"Moving" only works to transfer ownership of resources, and you can only do that if the resources are held indirectly, such as via a pointer. Then you can swap the pointer. But if you have to swap the actual data, then that's basically just a copy.

Most standard containers (such as `std::vector`, and excepting `std::array`) hold their data indirectly, behind a pointer, so these have useful move semantics.

Comment: So there is no Big difference between these 2 pieces of code if used in a vector, is this right ?

Comment: @ahmedamr • There is a huge difference between these 2 pieces of code if used in a vector.  Whether or not that difference matters only profiling can determine.

Comment: @Eljay A vector of `T` where `T` has move==copy will not have a "huge" difference or any other difference

Comment: A vector T where T has move==move, such as in the first piece of code, will have a huge difference compared to a vector of T where T has move==copy, such as in the second piece of code.

Comment: @Eljay I interpreted the question as being, will there be a difference between using the copy ctor and using the move ctor, inside a vector, when the move ctor is effectively equivalent to the copy ctor.

Comment: In the 2 pieces of code provided, the move is not equivalent to the copy.

Comment: @Eljay The premise of the question is _"if we assume that data is just a simple integer or even a very large uninitialized array"_. But that's fine looks like the OP got their answer

Comment: The "these 2 pieces of code" was ambiguous then.  I thought it was referring to the OP's provided two pieces of code.  I agree that a `move` of an int or simple struct that is done by copy (because it manages no resources) has the same identical characteristics as a copy of the same.

Answer (score 1):

> So there is no Big difference between these 2 pieces of code if used
>   in a vector, is this right ?

Difference will only appear if some object have changed the value pointed by pointer or an element of the array since it will affect all other objects, so if you don't have any intentions to modify the elements pointed by pointer or an element of the array your free 2 use either way, although it is better use Move semantics to make your code more error prone.